# how to get access to what textformfield shows

Tags: flutter, dart

i have textformfield i want to get access to what it shows
like when i print 10000 i want it to show and separate the int like 10,000 , i can print it with `regex` but i want to show it in text form field too
here us what i got in terminal (`left`) and what it shows in text field (`right`)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgc2N.png)

and all i wanna do is show what is in terminal to text field\

.
**if you need more information please let me know**
here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddTransication extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddTransicationState createState() => _AddTransicationState();
}

class _AddTransicationState extends State<AddTransication> {
  RegExp reg_ex = new RegExp(r'(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))');
  Function mathFunc = (Match match) => '${match[1]},';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Test Screen"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("Save"),
            shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Form(
          child: Column(
            children: [emailField(reg_ex, mathFunc)],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget emailField(reg_ex, mathFunc) {
    return TextFormField(
      onChanged: (str) {
        String result = str.replaceAllMapped(reg_ex, mathFunc);
        print(' $result');
      },
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Email Address',
        hintText: 'you@example.com',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter

Comment: check the above package id it might help, to ad mask to textinput

Comment: Check my answer, I have updated my answer and added the code that works as per your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739892/how-to-get-access-to-what-textformfield-shows/64740084#64740084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use TextEditingController class.

> A controller for an editable text field.

> Whenever the user modifies a text field with an associated TextEditingController, the text field updates value and the controller notifies its listeners. Listeners can then read the text and selection properties to learn what the user has typed or how the selection has been updated.

Refer : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html

Please check the code, below I have updated it to work as per your question.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: AddTransication(),
    );
  }
}

class AddTransication extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddTransicationState createState() => _AddTransicationState();
}

class _AddTransicationState extends State<AddTransication> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  RegExp regex = new RegExp(r'(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))');
  Function mathFunc = (Match match) => '${match[1]},';
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Test Screen"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("Save"),
            shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Form(
          child: Column(
            children: [emailField(regex, mathFunc)],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget emailField(regex, mathFunc) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _controller,
      onChanged: (str) {
        String text = str.replaceAll(",", "").replaceAllMapped(regex, mathFunc);
        print(' $text');
        _controller.value = _controller.value.copyWith(
          text: text,
          selection:
              TextSelection(baseOffset: text.length, extentOffset: text.length),
          composing: TextRange.empty,
        );
      },
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Email Address',
        hintText: 'you@example.com',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please replace ===> String text = _controller.text
          .replaceAll(",", "")
          .replaceAllMapped(regex, mathFunc);  <=== with whatever value you want to display. In the next line the value assigned to text is set back to the TextFormField

Comment: only a little problem , when i write 111111 text field show 111,111 but in console i got this 11,1111  how can i handle this?

Comment: I've updated the code, now it will display exactly as shown in console.